# KNN giving highest accuracy with K=1?

Tags: classification, weka, knn

I am using Weka's IBk for performing classification on text (tweets). I am converting the training and test data to vector space, and when I am performing the classification on test data, the best result comes from K=1. The training and testing data are separate from each other. Why does K=1 give the best accuracy?

Comment: What is the vector space that you are using? n-gram counts?

Comment: I'm vectorizing it through Weka, and using Bigrams as tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using vectors; so at `k=1` the value you get for proximity (for `k=1`) is more important than what the common class is in case of `k=n` (ex: when `k=5`)